# is this correct implementation of IoC?

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control

I'm trying to increase my Inversion of Control knowledge, and spotted some code that I'd like to know - is this true IoC?

```
    public class DepartmentLogic : IDepartmentLogic
    {
        private readonly IDepartmentRepository _departmentRepository;

        public DepartmentLogic(IDepartmentRepository repo)
        {
            _departmentRepository = repo;
        }

        public DepartmentLogic()
        {
            _departmentRepository = new DepartmentRepository(Constants.CONNECTION_STRING_NAME);
        }
    }
```

If the unit test calls this class, it'll pass in a mocked IDepartmentRepository. However, all the main application code uses the class with the default constructor, which then news up the concrete DepartmentRepository.

Is this correct? I thought I read that you shouldn't new up dependent classes within your calling class, like is happening in the default constructor, and that the newing of the concrete DepartmentRepository should really happen in the class that created this class.

Comment: You're right. That code is entirely defeating the purpose of IoC and ending up with tightly coupled types. It looks like they created the IoC constructor just for the purposes of unit testing rather than embracing it as an overall design methodology.

Comment: Thanks, @itsme86 - that's what I was worried about. When I question it, I'm asked, "besides unit testing, there's no other reason for IoC", and I end up not being sure how to respond. I believe the statement is invalid, and there are numerous reasons, but I can't seem to pick any. Can you assist?

Comment: I guess [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)#Disadvantages) sums up the disadvantages of tight coupling pretty well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're providing the ability to have the dependency injected into the class.

When you say that your application simply uses the default constructor, you're saying that you haven't actually injected the dependency. It's still hard coded.

You need to go another step further and provide some mechanism for "dynamically" creating the dependency at run time and then injecting it into the class (via a Dependency Injection Framework or some other custom mechanism).

Comment: Thanks @Justin... When you say " provide some mechanism for "dynamically" creating the dependency", do you mean something like Unity (An IoC container - the next thing I am trying to get a better understanding of)

Comment: @Craig - Correct (hence why I mentioned Dependency Injection Frameworks). Unity is just one of them. I also like Autofac and nInject.

Comment: Anytime you use the "new" keyword in constructor it introduces tight coupling,